# How do I link these two basic programs together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Its my first time coding on python, I want to link these two files together but don't know how to. I want the program to redirect the user to the second program if they have a private number plate but How do i make this link?

I just need a simple code nothing to advanced as I will get confused. I need to learn how to use these codes before I move on to the more advanced codes for linking files together.

```
# program1.py
privateNumberPlate = open("privateNumberPlate.txt", 'a')
ordinaryNum = open("ordinaryNum.txt", 'a')

print ("Welcome")
plateSelections = ("What is your number plate?", "If you own a private number plate please press 1 to be redirected")
```

```
# program2.py
print ("You have been redirected", "Please enter your private number plate.")
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. And nobody should ever have to click a link to see your code. Put it here (edit your question).

Comment: if you want to use program 1 in program 2, use import program1 on program 2 or from program1 import *

Answer (score 2):

You'll need functions for that. Let's say your first programs name is Program1.py and second Program2.py. In Program2.py you should have a function like this:

```
def Function_Name():
    print("You have been redirected....")
```

Program1.py and Program2.py should be in the same folder. Then you add this to Program1.py:

```
from Program2 import Function_Name
```

and then you call that function like this:

```
Function_Name()
```

and it should print out what you wanted. Hope this helped.